# How to write in a console application from another

Tags: .net, console, extern

I search for a solution how to write into an external console application from another. I look for a C# or C++ solution.

For short I want to change the color and clear the console from an already existing console application from extern. I also want to write some lines into it.

I do not have access to the source of the second app.

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are the difficulities you come up with? Please read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section, it helps you getting faster and more accurate answers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command-line arguments and then receive the parameters in the other console application String [] args for example:
call for:

```
App2.exe "red"
```

from App1,
and in App2 :

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    if(args[1].equals("red");
        this.background("red");
  }
}
```

the code I wrote is just an example and not the best practice.

Comment: I do not have access to edit the source of the second app. So this solution will not work.